# Is there a way to count auto-incrementally?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The question is:

Get the 5 podcasts with the most views, each listen is counted if `timeDuration > 29s` (only taking active songs). Each 29s will count as 1 TIMES so it will count base on PodcastID. 1 podcast with multiple episodes, 1 episode of multiple podcasts.
I think im using JOIN wrong condition so it can not get what I want.

Here is what I have tried:

```
SELECT TOP (5) E.ID,E.Name,R.PodcastID,
COUNT (R.PodcastID) TIMES
FROM (REPORT R JOIN EPISODE E ON R.PodcastID = E.PodcastID) JOIN 
PODCAST P ON P.ID = E.ID 
WHERE R.TimeDuration > 29 AND E.Status = 1
GROUP BY E.ID, E.Name,R.PodcastID
ORDER BY TIMES;
```

Here is the 3 Tables that I have created:

[image]

--But the output, at the column TIMES no matter I do they only count as 1, although I have set the variable above that: 58s, 116s ( mean 2, 4 times)

Here is the result I want but get top5 only, in the picture is 6 results although I Select top(5)..

[image]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Is the data you are showing your results or your sample data? Either way we need a complete [mre] with sample data, desired results as well as your query.

Comment: We will need to see your tables to see what is wrong.  maybe something in your joins creates the problem.  try 1st removing the top 5 and see if you get duplicated songs.  if you do get duplicated songs try removing your join and see how it will behave

Comment: Please post full  tables structure and data, it's not possible to replicate if we don't see that

Comment: Because you `GROUP BY` `R.TimeDuration`. Remove that from the `GROUP BY ` clause

Comment: Count will simply count the number of rows in the aggregation. I don't think that is what you want here. It sounds like you want to use sum(r.TimeDuration) / 29 or something like that. With no sample data or desired output it is really just a guess.

Comment: Your error is by including the R.TimeDuration in the Group By clause, as this will render every R.TimeDuration as a single count(1) unless there are two R.TimeDuration with exactly the same value for the same podcast, as the COUNT() is an aggregate function, hence the reason you are using the Group By to begin with. You simply need a value of 1 for each row where R.TimeDuration > 29 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then a report row means, someone listened to music in the podcast. The row contains the duration in seconds which you want to regard as a number of blocks of 29 seconds. So, divide the durations by 29 and work with this.

```
with listened as
(
  select
    id as id_podcast,
    sum(timeduration / 29) as times,
  from report1
  where timeduration > 29
  group by id
)
select top(5) with ties
  p.*, listened.times
from podcast p
join listened on listened.id_podcast = p.id
where  p.status = 1
order by listened.times desc;
```

It looks strange that you join podcast and report on their IDs. The ID of a report should identify a report not a podcast. Well, I just used it as you did, but created an alias name to make this readable. If this was a mere mistake on your side, then it will be easy to correct this.

If timedureation is an integer, SQL Server will apply integer division by the way. If you want to work with fractions, divide by 29.0 instead of by 29. This may result in much higher time totals per podcast.

I am using the `WITH TIES` clause, which is common when looking for the top n rows. If you want to restrict this to five result rows where you may have to pick rows from the complete top list arbitrarily, then remove that clause.